# how to group graphic object

Tags: java

how to turn several graphics objects in to one?
(this part of code should generate tetris figure, where generate() create a figure)

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
        Figure f = generate();
        int length = f.getX()[0].length;
        for(int j =0; j<f.getX().length;j++){

            int xr=xs+10;
            ys = 0;                 
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++){                      

                if (f.getX()[j][i] == 1){
                    int yr = ys+10;
                    Rectangle p = new Rectangle(xs,ys,xr,yr);
                    g.setColor(f.getY());
                    g.drawRect(p.x, p.y, p.width, p.height);    
                    g.fillRect(p.x, p.y, p.width, p.height);    
                    //g.translate(xs+40, ys+40);
                }
                ys+=10;

            }
            xs+=10;
        }
        xs=0;
        ys=0;


       //g.setColor(Color.white);
       //g.drawRect(45, 95, 55, 105);

    }
```

Comment: What you want to do? To use one graphic context for each figure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you are starting with Java 2D, since your code has some problems.
First of all, you always need to call the paint version of the super class. This should be done because the component needs to have a chance to render itself properly. Take a look.

```
@Override
public void paint( Graphics g ) {

    // you MUST do this
    super.paint(g);

    // continue here... 

}
```

If you are dealing with a JFrame you will override the paint method. If you are working with some JComponent child, like JPanel, you need to override the paintComponent method, which has the same signature of paint, but it is protected, not public. You can override paint too, but in these cases (JComponent and its children), paint is a method that delegates the paint work to three methods (paintComponent, paintBorder, and paintChildren), so the best option is to override paintComponent.

Another detail. The best way to work with graphics is to create a new graphics context based in the current one and dispose of it after using it. Take a look:

```
@Override
public void paint( Graphics g ) {

    // you MUST do this
    super.paint(g);

    Graphics newG = g.create();
    // or Graphics2D newG2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    // do your work here...

    newG.dispose(); // disposes the graphics context

}
```

The graphics context that is created using the create method is a copy of the current graphics context (with the same states), but changing it does not affect the original one, so doing this, you will not mess with the state of the original graphics context.

To finish, I think that you need to have a draw method in your figure that receives the graphics context. So, the Figure instance will be responsible to draw itself. Something like:

```
public class Figure {

    // figure's members...

    public void drawMe( Graphics2D g2d ) {
        // do the draw work here...
    }

}

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    @Override
    public void paint( Graphics g ) {

        super.paint(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        // let's suppose that figureList is a List<Figure> or a Figure[]
        for ( Figure f : figureList ) {
            f.drawMe( g2d );
        }

        g2d.dispose();

    }

}
```

Of course, you can create a new graphics context for each Figure if its draw method changes the graphics context too "deeply", like doing translations and rotations. You just need to dispose the new ones after using them.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to put multiple components inside of an enclosing component so that you can move/manipulate them together.

One suggestion would be to add each of your objects to a panel object, like `JPanel`.

However it is somewhat unclear what you are trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: it drows  piture on aplet wich consist of 10X10 pixel rectangle.But when i am trying to manipulate that picture, each block is affected separatly